# How to extract classes from SOAP XML via PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, soapui, soap-client

Im new to SOAP UI, so is there any method to extract key->value pairs from SOAP UI. I.e. reading "index" of what SOAP interface has to offer? Like reading MIB from SNMP?

For example I can request:

```
<SOAP:Body>
    <find xmlns="xmlapi">
            <fullClassName>Persons</fullClassName>
            <resultFilter class="Persons.Data">
            <attribute>Name</attribute>
            </resultFilter>
    </find>
 </SOAP:Body>
```

Class name "Persons" is what I know, but is there a way to retrieve list of "classes" SOAP UI has to offer?

Comment: The description is not making the problem clear? Would it be possible to edit the question and add more details such as what are you trying to achieve using soapui? What do you mean by `extracting classes`?

Comment: Hi Rao, thanks for your reply. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. So is the find element repetitive and that is why are asking for list of `fullClassName`?

Comment: I assume all "FullClassName" objects are under the find element. Im asking for a way to retrieve list of all objects under the find element.

Comment: Do yo mean to say that you wanted to find all the possible values for `fullClassName`? If so, then the best thing you could do is to check with the service provider or your team if it is internal service. Another possibility is that to check the wsdl / xml schema definition to see if those are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all `<fullClassName>` elements inside `<find>` for a specific request, a possible way is for example using [*XmlSlurper*](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) inside a *groovy testStep*:

```java
// get your response 
def response = context.expand( '${TestRequest#Response}' )
// parse it
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
// find all `<fullClassName>` in your xml
def classNames = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'fullClassName' }
// print all values
classNames.each{
    log.info "fullClassName: $it"
}
```

As you are new to *SOAPUI* (maybe also to *Groovy*) here are some hints:

`context.expand( '${TestRequestName#Property}' )` get the content of the specific property from some scoped element. In your case you've to specify your request name and as a property the Response. For more info see [*property expansion documentation*](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html)

*Groovy* automatically use `it` as a variable for the closures. This is why I use `it` in `each` and in `findAll`.

**UPDATE**

If you want to know all possible values supported by `<fullClassName>` you've the follow options:

1. Check if the type for `<fullClassName>` defined in the *schema* has a `<xs:restiction>` with `<xs:enumeration>` with the possible values.
2. If in the *schema* the type it's simply an `<xs:string>` or other type which doesn't give you any clue about the allowed value, contact the provider to see an alternative like if there is another SOAP service which returns the values...

For the first case if you've the `.xsd` try adding a *groovy testStep* to parse the `.xsd` and get the `<xs:enumeration>` values, see the follow example:

```java
def xsd = '''<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<simpleType name="fullClassNameType">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="Persons"/>
        <enumeration value="AnotherClassName"/>
        <enumeration value="AnotherOne"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
</schema>'''

// parse the xsd 
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xsd )
// find your type by name attribute
def fullClassNameType = xml.depthFirst().find { it.@name == 'fullClassNameType' }
// get an array with value attribute of enumeration elements
def allowedValues = fullClassNameType.restriction.enumeration*.@value
log.info allowedValues // [Persons, AnotherClassName, AnotherOne]
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry about my short title, I'm working with PHP, so is there a way to do it in PHP?

Comment: @user1712484 probably I didn't understand your question, what do you want exactly? At first I think that you're looking for a way to check the `<fullClassName>` of your server response, however after your comment seems that you're looking for a way to implement it in a sever side, isn't it?

Comment: Im implementing this on client side. So basically, I'm fetching data via SOAP from server, and I only know element <fullClassName>Persons</fullClassName>. I'm asking if there is a way to list all elements that this particular SOAP API has to offer. Referring to MIB file in SNMP.

Comment: @user1712484 know I understand... if `<fullClassName>` has a *restriction* in the *schema* definition then you can see the possible values in the *schema* itself. However if its type is simply for example a `<xs:string>` then the values depends totally on your server implementation... so there is no standard way to get all values. However there are some things you can do... or as I said use a *restriction* on the *schema* to specify allowed values or you can implement a other operation in your server to get all values you support for this case...

Comment: @user1712484, when the problem is ours, we have to be responsible for providing enough details so that other members of the community can understand it better and provide solution possibly. If we do not pay attention for our own problem, who else will do? And making other people spend time and finally say need something different. Be mindful of others time too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Is is possible to retrieve the schema via SOAP API?

Comment: @user1712484 I update my answer, take a look on it `:)`